# Define plot label outside plt.plot() command - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm making a scatter plot that uses two different symbols based on a condition in the data.
In a for loop iterating through the rows of the data, if a condition is met a point is plotted with a circle, and if not met the point is plotted with a square:

```
for i in thick.index:
    if thick['Interest'][i] == 1:
        plt.scatter(thick['NiThickness'][i], thick['GdThickness'][i], marker = 'o', color = 'b')
    else:
        plt.scatter(thick['NiThickness'][i], thick['GdThickness'][i], marker = 's', color = 'r')
```

where 'Interest' is a column filled with ones and zeros(zeroes?).

I'd like to have one label in the legend for the circles, and one for the squares, but if I declare `label = 'circle'` in the `plt.scatter(...)` command I get as many rows in the legend as there rows in my data file.

Is there a simple trick I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the pattern I use in such cases:

```
label_o = 'Circle'
label_s = 'Square'
for i in thick.index:
    if thick['Interest'][i] == 1:
        plt.scatter(thick['NiThickness'][i], thick['GdThickness'][i], marker=o', color='b', label=label_o)
        label_o = None
    else:
        plt.scatter(thick['NiThickness'][i], thick['GdThickness'][i], marker='s', color='r', label=label_s)
        label_s = None
```

This also nicely takes care of the case where only one of the categories is present.

Answer (score 1):

if `thick` is a data-frame:

```
idx = thick['Interest'] == 1
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.scatter(thick['NiThickness'][idx], thick['GdThickness'][idx],
           marker='o', color='b', label='circle')
ax.scatter(thick['NiThickness'][~idx], thick['GdThickness'][~idx],
           marker='s', color='r', label='square')
```